# How to send messages on threads?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I currently have code for a command that takes in a channel ID followed by some text message as input. The code then finds the channel and sends the message on it. However, Discord has just released a new thread feature, and currently, no update has been made to the official [Discord API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) regarding how bots can interact with threads. So, how can a bot send messages to threads? Please leave down answers as new information is released by Discord. Here's the code I was talking about before:

```py
@bot.command()
async def text(ctx, channel_id, *, msg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(channel_id))
    try:
        await channel.send(ctx.message.attachments[0].url)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    await channel.trigger_typing()
    await channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: Threads will be supported since discord.py 2.0+ (in beta, no ETA). If you want to use it now, install it using `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, the docs are here [master docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html). [`discord.Thread`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=thread#discord.Thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [discord.py 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), threads are supported with [`discord.Thread`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Thread).

#### get_thread

###### 1. [Using `discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_thread)

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    thread = ctx.guild.get_thread(thread_id)
```

There is also the method [`get_channel_or_thread`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel_or_thread) which returns either a channel or a thread.

```py
    channel_or_thread = ctx.guild.get_channel_or_thread(channel_id)
```

###### 2. [Using `discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.get_thread)

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    thread = ctx.channel.get_thread(thread_id)
```

---

#### threads

###### 1. [Using `discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.threads)

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    threads = ctx.guild.threads
```

There is also the coroutine [`active_threads`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.active_threads) which returns all active threads which the bot can see

```py
    active_threads = await ctx.guild.active_threads()
```

###### 2. [Using `discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.threads)

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    threads = ctx.channel.threads
```

There is also the async iterator [`archived_threads`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.archived_threads) that iterates over all archived threads in this text channel

```
    async for thread in ctx.channel.archived_threads():
        # ...
```